# lambda working oddly with tkinter

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I am trying to make a calculator using Tkinter. I have been trying to clean up the code a bit but have run into a snag. When creating buttons, I use the following code:

```
Button(self,text="1",command=lambda: self.addkey("1"),width=self.defaultwidth,height=self.defaultheight).grid(row=5, column=0)
Button(self,text="2",command=lambda: self.addkey("2"),width=self.defaultwidth,height=self.defaultheight).grid(row=5, column=1)
Button(self,text="3",command=lambda: self.addkey("3"),width=self.defaultwidth,height=self.defaultheight).grid(row=5, column=2)
```

With the following being the command called

```
def addkey(self,key):
            # Adds a given key to the display
            if len(self.displaytext) + len(key) <= self.maxlength:
                self.displaytext += key
                self.display["text"] = self.displaytext
```

When buttons 1, 2, and 3 are pressed in that order, the following is the output:

```
123
```

I have been trying to clean up the code so that it looks more like:

```
for i in range(3):
    Button(self,text=str(i+1),command=lambda: self.addkey(str(i+1)),width=self.defaultwidth,height=self.defaultheight).grid(row=5, column=i)
```

This adds the buttons fine, but when 1, 2, and 3 are pressed in that order, the following shows up on the screen:

```
333
```

I was wondering if I missed something or this is simply not possible.

Comment: Could you post more code? I'm assuming that this button creation code is being run from the class's `__init__()` method?

Comment: I think this is a classic Python lexical scoping gotcha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, scoping. When you do this:

```
command=lambda: self.addkey(str(i))
```

You're **not** "resolving" the `i` to a number **right there and then**. You're just telling the lambda to reference `i` when it's invoked, **afterwards**.

At any time past the end of the `for` loop, `i = 3` (last value), so all of your lambdas get `3` when they ask for `i`.

If I'm not mistaken, you can add a function as means of indirection, and it will appropriately "capture" `i` from the surrounding scope.

```
def add_key_f(i):
    return lambda self: self.addkey(i)
```

Comment: the classic workaround for this problem (other than the one you mention) is to add a keyword arg: `command=lambda i=i: self.addkey(str(i))`

Comment: Another option: `command=functools.partial(self.addkey, str(i))`.

Comment: Interesting! I'd never seen either approach! The default argument is dirty, but oh _so clever_!

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: it's not dirty, it's the proper way to use lambda.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's a bit dirty because it's a misuse of the keyword argument mechanism to import a value into the lambda (which doesn't otherwise use or need the `i` parameter). However, it's very short, easy to understand, and it *is* a Python idiom, so its use should not be considered obfuscation.

Comment: @user4815162342: I completely disagree. You are simply using a built-in feature to do exactly what the feature is designed to do.

Comment: How are defaults **designed** to close over variables in lexical scope?

Comment: @BryanOakley Keyword parameters are *designed* to equip functions with optional keyword arguments. If you define a function as `def foo(arg=DFLT)`, it is expected that someone will, at some point, call `foo(VALUE)` or `foo(arg=VALUE)`. In this case nothing of the sort happens or can *ever* happen, and the keyword argument is only used to inject the equivalent of an `arg = VALUE` into *this* instance of the `lambda`. That is a clever hack, and is surely not what keyword arguments were designed for — and it cannot possibly have been, since closures didn't even exist at the time.