# Lambda function behavior with and without keyword arguments

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I am using lambda functions for GUI programming with tkinter.
Recently I got stuck when implementing buttons that open files:

```
self.file=""
button = Button(conf_f, text="Tools opt.",
        command=lambda: tktb.helpers.openfile(self.file))
```

As you see, I want to define a file path that can be updated, and that is not known when creating the GUI.
The issue I had is that earlier my code was :

```
button = Button(conf_f, text="Tools opt.",
        command=lambda f=self.file: tktb.helpers.openfile(f))
```

The lambda function had a keyword argument to pass the file path. In this case, the parameter `f` was not updated when `self.file` was.

I got the keyword argument from a code snippet and I use it everywhere. Obviously I shouldn't...

This is still not clear to me... Could someone explain me the difference between the two lambda forms and when to use one an another?

PS: The following comment led me to the solution but I'd like a little more explanations:
[lambda working oddly with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305153/lambda-working-oddly-with-tkinter#comment21603218_15305225)

Comment: What more explanation do you need?  The accepted answer to the question you linked to explains the difference pretty succinctly.

Comment: In fact, I'd like to understand why the argument value can be updated or not depending of the coding style.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll try to explain it more in depth.

If you do

```
i = 0
f = lambda: i
```

you create a function (lambda is essentially a function) which accesses its enclosing scope's `i` variable.

Internally, it does so by having a so-called closure which contains the `i`. It is, loosely spoken, a kind of pointer to the real variable which can hold different values at different points of time.

```
def a():
    # first, yield a function to access i
    yield lambda: i
    # now, set i to different values successively
    for i in range(100): yield

g = a() # create generator
f = next(g) # get the function
f() # -> error as i is not set yet
next(g)
f() # -> 0
next(g)
f() # -> 1
# and so on
f.func_closure # -> an object stemming from the local scope of a()
f.func_closure[0].cell_contents # -> the current value of this variable
```

Here, all values of `i` are - at their time - stored in that said closure. If the function `f()` needs them. it gets them from there.

You can see that difference on the disassembly listings:

These said functions `a()` and `f()` disassemble like this:

```
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (i)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0xb72ea650, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             12 YIELD_VALUE
             13 POP_TOP

  3          14 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 42)
             17 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             20 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             23 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 GET_ITER
        >>   27 FOR_ITER                11 (to 41)
             30 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)
             33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 YIELD_VALUE
             37 POP_TOP
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           27
        >>   41 POP_BLOCK
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (i)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compare that to a function `b()` which looks like

```
>>> def b():
...   for i in range(100): yield
>>> dis.dis(b)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 28)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                11 (to 27)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 YIELD_VALUE
             23 POP_TOP
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   27 POP_BLOCK
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

The main difference in the loop is

```
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                11 (to 27)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
```

in `b()` vs.

```
        >>   27 FOR_ITER                11 (to 41)
             30 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)
```

in `a()`: the `STORE_DEREF` stores in a `cell` object (closure), while `STORE_FAST` uses a "normal" variable, which (probably) works a little bit faster.

The lambda as well makes a difference:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: i)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here you have a `LOAD_GLOBAL`, while the one above uses `LOAD_DEREF`. The latter, as well, is for the closure.

I completely forgot about `lambda i=i: i`.

If you have the value as a default parameter, it finds its way into the function via a completely different path: the current value of `i` gets passed to the just created function via a default parameter:

```
>>> i = 42
>>> f = lambda i=i: i
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

This way the function gets called as `f()`. It detects that there is a missing argument and fills the respective parameter with the default value. All this happens before the function is called; from within the function you just see that the value is taken and returned.

And there is yet another way to accomplish your task: Just use the lambda as if it would take a value: `lambda i: i`. If you call this, it complains about a missing argument.

But you can cope with that with the use of `functools.partial`:

```
ff = [functools.partial(lambda i: i, x) for x in range(100)]
ff[12]()
ff[54]()
```

This wrapper gets a callable and a number of arguments to be passed. The resulting object is a callable which calls the original callable with these arguments plus any arguments you give to it. It can be used here to keep locked to the value intended.

Comment: So if I want to see the difference I need to run: 1/ `dis.dis(lambda: i)` and 2/ `dis.dis(lambda i=i: i)`. I'll get one `LOAD_GLOBAL` and one `LOAD_DEREF` (hope I am right...). I can't do this now but I'll try tomorrow. Thank you very much for your answer! I also need further reading on function closures. I never heard anything about that...

Comment: @Plouff Roughly spoken, yes. I just added some more thoughts about that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I can't say everything is clear now since I am not so used to this kind of thing. But I think I understood the most important parts. I also noticed that it was the tkinter bindings that mess up my mind. Since you need to pass the `event` as argument, you need argument in lambda. After that, each time I needed lambda functions, I used kwd arguments. And that was not correct...

Comment: @Plouff It is not an easy subject; the best is to remember that access to an "outermore" variable means accessing the value at the time of execution, not at the time of definition.

Comment: In my case I'll try to remember the contrapositive statement:  default values of keyword arguments are stored at definition even in lambda functions. I thought a pointer was stored instead of a value.